# Observer for event on Checkout button click of Minicart Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, mini-cart

I want to create observer for event which is responsible to send data from minicart to checkout.

Please suggest event name.

I have already tried:

> checkout_cart_update_items_before

and

> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index

Comment: what do you mean by "send data from minicart to checkout"? both is using the same quote

Comment: Minicart button is only an link which directed to checkout and controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index event will trigger and post your checkout url here

Comment: I have some custom fields in minicart which i want to get saved on click of checkout button. i have already tried controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index but it does not called on click of minicart checkout button

Comment: Add that to quote using ajax, that would work out for you @Khushbu